# Where should Apple Watch Complication data be stored?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I need to store data that's controlled by the main Watch app (and the iPhone app) and displayed in a complication.

The [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ManagingComplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH28-SW1) says

> If you need to fetch or compute the data for your complication, do it
>   in your iOS app or in other parts of your WatchKit extension (for
>   example, by scheduling a background app refresh task), and **cache the
>   data in a place** where your complication data source can access it.

What do they have in mind when they tell you to cache the data in a place where the complication can access it?  What is the best practice/standard way to achieve this?

Comment: any idea if group directory works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store some data in UserDefaults, and access that from your complication data source.

ie.

```
//In a background task
func getComplicationData(){
    let yourData = someNetworkCall()
    /* 
    yourData = [
        "complicationHeader": "Some string",
        "complicationInner": "Some other stirng"
    ]


    */
    UserDefaults.standard.set(yourData, forKey: "complicationData")
}
```

Then in your ComplicationDataSource

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {

    if let yourData = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "complicationData") as? [String: String] {
        //Handle setting up templates for complications
    }

}
```

Comment: I read somewhere that using UserDefaults too much was seen as a shortcut or a hack and not the intended way of storing data.  Is there a significant downside to doing it this way?

Comment: Yes *and* no, you should try and store only things you need to in it, otherwise you can use CoreData. But I feel like it works well here

Comment: Ther is no shared Userdefaults between iOS & WatchOS.